# Table Align Centre does not Align Centre

Tags: ckeditor

I'm building a simple table in CKEditor. If I select Left or Right align, it aligns in the expected side of the view when saved. However, when saved this fails if I select Centre align. It's obviously not the whole page because Centre Align text above and below will display Centre aligned. This issue only becomes apparent when "saved" ... (ie a centre aligned table will centre align in edit).

Can you suggest what's going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How is the centering actually performed? If you have configured using the XHTML configuration, this sounds like a class issue - if not, it could be a CSS `!important` override rule.

I have CKE configured based on the XHTML example, so my CKE produces centering on table cells like this: `<td class="JustifyCenter">Twilight Sparkle</td>`. So, if you place the HTML generated by CKEditor in an external page, make sure that the `JustifyCenter` class actually defined in the parent page. Also in Developer tools that not only it the class rule exists, that it is actually correct and applies.

Also in your developer tools and check to see if your CSS style is actually working or is it being overridden. If you have a parent page CSS rule like `td {text-align:left !important;}` and CKE produces content like `<td style="text-align:center">Fluttershy</td>`, the parent page is overriding your inline CSS definition.

I'm only guessing here - it would help if you can you show us the final code as it's used when saved and also your CKEditor configuration.

Answer (score 0):

the table align to center CKeditor will generate something like this, `<table align="center">`
but it is not working.

finally i found a solution by using CSS, here my code

```
table[align="center"] {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```